# "At most as many" — what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, superlative-degree

I've been given the following question as a homework:

> If *h* is consistent, then *A* - CSCS* will expand **at most as many** nodes as *A* graph search*.

English not being my native language, I'm kind of struggling to understand the true meaning of the text in bold in the context of this sentence.

From what I understand, *A* - CSCS* will always expand fewer or the same amount of nodes then *A* graph* search. That is, the number of nodes that *A* graph search* expands will always be larger or equal to the number of nodes that *A* - CSCS* expands.

Is this correct?

Sorry for bringing out the question involving mathematics. What I need is a linguistic explanation of the sentence, not help in mathematics.

Comment: It's probably the lack of commas that's throwing you off: _If h is consistent, then `A* - CSCS` will expand, at most, as many nodes as A* graph search._

Comment: General Reference - *at most* = *up to, but not more than*, and *as many X as...* = *the same number of X as...*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct.

Read it this way:

> If *h* is consistent, then **at most**  *A** - *CSCS* will expand **as many** nodes as *A** *graph search*.

Or, more naturally:

> If *h* is consistent, then *A** - *CSCS* will **not** expand **any more** nodes **than** *A** *graph search*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your understanding is correct. *At most as many as* can usually be replaced by *no more than*; I don't know why the author chose this unusual form of words.

Comment: Because discussions of algorithms often include their bounding conditions, "at most" is the usual way of expressing it, while "no more than" can be confusing.  In this case, the bounding condition is best expressed as equivalent to another well-understood condition, and therefore the two phrases are juxtaposed in a construction that is odd for English, but correct for the mathematical formulation.